# NDK adding prebuilt library.Correct method

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is this the correct format to specify the Android.mk?Is there any syntax errors? I couldnt find any source for clearing this doubt.Thanking you in advance.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := imageprocessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := imageprocessing.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libfreeimage
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfreeimage.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and in the C code have

```
#include <android/libfreeimage.h>
```

Comment: If it works for you then it's correct otherwise it's not correct. Is there any specific problem you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
I got the solution from
http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/PREBUILTS.html
Thank you for your valuable time Subrat nayak,thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

since u r creating a shared library from an existing shared library: So u need to first give the pre-built shared library part first then u can create ur own library. so ur code should look like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libfreeimage
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libfreeimage.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := imageprocessing
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := imageprocessing.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: i m getting u... if ur library **libfreeimage** contains the 'libfreeimage.h' then u have to keep in mind tht the 'libfreeimage.h' file is available to ur application.

Comment: I have no clue what libfreeimage.h includes...it is a prebuilt library which I downloaded for image manipulation...So what am I supposed to write in the NDK C code to include the library??

Comment: so whn evr u r using the fuctions present inside **libfreeimage** library,and u r getting _error:undefined reference to function()_ this error thn think that u have to make _libfreeimage.h_ file available to ur project...

Comment: See....all I want to know is how can I add a reference of the library into the C code I use? Addtn info: It is in the same directory as the android.mk file..

Comment: then use **LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := path/to/folder(whr ur file is present)**

Comment: u hv to put that line of code before **include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)** line

Comment: ur .so file will be generated inside libs, u have to put it into armeabi folder.....one thing don't forget to accept answers which helps  and which can help others also.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14263/discussion-between-sreekanth-karumanaghat-and-subrat-nayak)